# Bootstrap basic grid layout conflict

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A portion of a site I am working on has a two-column design. I would like this to be implemented for all screen sizes, except on `xs` devices. On `xs` devices, I would like a single column design. I feel like the below approach is incorrect, as the col-span should always add up to 12 in all cases, and it is currently not the case for xs screens. On the other hand, if I change it `col-xs-6`, it is forcing double column designs on extra small screens, which I am trying to avoid.

What is the correct way to accomplish a single column design on extra smalls screens, while maintaining a double column design on all other screen sizes ?

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="ac-wrapper">
                <div class="ac-h">
                    Heading 2
                </div>
                <p class="ac-p">
                text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text her text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="ac-wrapper">
                <div class="ac-h">
                    Heading 123
                </div>
                <p class="ac-p">
                    text here text here text here text here text here text here text her text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text her text here text here text here text here 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to toggle content visibility using http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: +1, Thank you, did not know that, is it possible to hide the entire row / container based on screen size ?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that. It is a very useful class. I have used it in the past to hide  various sections of my websites on smaller screens. For example, removing the sidebars or advertisements from phone screens.